# Javascript: ajax trouble with requests arrays

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

I'm fairly new to javascript and I'm still trying to grasp callback concepts. Even then, I'm not sure I have an issue with callbacks or ajax itself.

So I have this callback function which basically takes an array of objects somewhere else in my code.

```js
function powerAmplifierInfo(id, cb) {
  ApiGet('/system/radio-frequency/tx/' + id + '/power-amplifier', function (err, result) {
    if (err && !TESTING) {
      alertError("Connection error: " + err.statusText);
      return;
    } else if (result && result.result.code !== "OK") {
      alertError(result.result.message);
      return;
    }

    if (TESTING) {
      result = { powerAmplifier: "TEST model", uptime: Date.now() };
    }

    cb(result.powerAmplifier);
  });
}
```

This function uses another function which uses ajax to send a get request to some server.

```js
function ApiGet(urlSuffix, cb) {
  var url = apiPrefix + "/" + urlSuffix;

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (result) {
      cb(null, result);
    },
    error: function (err) {
      cb(err, null);
    }
  });
}
```

Now, the request chains in my list works but sometimes requests get mixed up together when I rerun the code in loop as it seems ajax switch some port orders while sending requests. I found out this issue while troubleshooting my local network with Wireshark. Here's an image to show it:
[image: Wireshark port mixup image]

The Get requests are sent but between the 3rd and the 4th ones, there is a port mixup. As we can see, the server replies without the port order mixup.

I'm wondering, is this a known issue or would there be a problem with my code, or even my server? I do not get this error when sending a single object in my callback functions instead of an object array.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous, there's no guarantee that responses will come in the same order that the requests were sent.

Comment: the order should not matter... the ajax request should still get the right response

Comment: Why is mixup an issue? The appropriate callback will be called when the response is received. You normally don't need to worry about this

Comment: After further testing, it does seem like I cannot assume the responses IDs will be in the same order as the requests because of ajax default asynchronous behavior. Forcing it to synchronous is a patch but not very efficient or a good practice as far as I know, but at least it works.